# Is customizing Navigation Bar allowed/possible?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uinavigationbar

I feel that the navigation bar in my app would be better off with a greater height than what is provided as is by default. Is changing the height of the navigation bar possible?

And if possible, is it permissible under the HIG? I scanned through the HIG document which places restrictions on many things but I couldn't find anywhere where it says the bar must be the default height. Can anyone confirm?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you feel this way? Have you done usability testing that indicates the standard height is too small?

Comment: I feel this way because I intend to stick up a segment control with icons (images + text overlaid) on the navigation bar. My iphone tag might be misleading, but this is for the ipad, hence the need for the icons on the segment to look bigger and more prominent like a dashboard of controls. I tried doing it using the default height of the bar and the end result isn't effective, it rather looks terrible. Text only segment control looks fine, but when I want to have images as icons for the segment it isn't. And using customized buttons don't address that "look" in any way either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change your navigation bar height and style. in my apps for example when i need a custom navigation bar i just set the navigationController's navigationBarHidden property to YES and add an UIView subclass that has the desired height, background, buttons..etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's allowed and it's possible.
Many apps customized their's navigation style(reeder, ibook,etc..)

and by default navigation bar have 2 different height, one is normal , another one is with prompt title.

But if you need change the height to another one. Maybe you need some more magic codes :D